# Searching in Java

Tags: java, search

I have array of Strings like

```
'Java Script'
'Microsoft Windows'
'Apple'
'Java'
```

I want to create search engine to search matching string of characters.
My problem is when user type word which is not exactly like in array.
Example:

```
jav skript -> should find : Java Script
MicrosoftWindow -> should find : 'Microsoft Windows'
Aples -> should find : 'Apple'
jjava -> should find : 'Java'
```

Is any ready solution to handle with that ?

Comment: Do you know about Solr Lucene because this is way too complicated to address on a stackoverflow answer?

Comment: In your case with only four different strings, this is very simple, however the more strings you get, the more complex this gets. It is not a job for mere mortals like you and I. But addressing this case, you could probably just return the string which has the highest ratio of matched/unmatched letters with the inputted string

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 4):

## Solr Lucene is perfect for what you are asking about

Solr, **written in Java**, is used by Duck Duck Go and powers Elastic Search. You'll have immediate functionality that feels a lot like having Google search quality minus the AI part.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

I use this in production on a number of applications and its probably one of the best open source projects out there. It works beautifully.

Here's how you can set one up on Digital Ocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04